# How to grab audio/voice from flash webcam and convert it to web based language

Tags: php, javascript, flash, webcam

I'm running a project about webcam chat with the major requirement being a translation system. I have no issue about how to translate it, but the only problem is how can I grab the voice when someone talk on the webcam, so I can convert the voice using voice recognition script and generate it into any function I want.

Does anyone know how could I solve this issue? What kind of language should I use? Is there any software required to be installed?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you looking to capture the audio in HTML or Flash, I wasn't sure from reading the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is WebRTC (web Real time communication).

Please have a look on these articles, it will definitely help you [WebRTC](http://www.telepresence24.com/?p=1804)

This is **[working example](http://www.webrtcexample.com/chat)** & this is [**code link**](https://github.com/fycth/webrtcexample) for it